# Add SPACE to CONCAT with SUBSTR Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, substr

I'm trying to join two columns together with a space separated and the first column requiring a SUBSTR and the other not. I have written this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR(FIRST_NAME,1,1), ' ',LAST_NAME) AS NAME
FROM OEHR_EMPLOYEES;
```

However I have tried numerous searching online and tried different ways to get it to work and I cannot. I get numerous errors. The result I am trying to get is for example if the raw data was Ray Adams then the result would be R Adams. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use Concatenation Operator:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(FIRST_NAME,1,1)|| ' '||LAST_NAME AS NAME FROM OEHR_EMPLOYEES;
```

Or nested concat function:

```
SELECT concat(CONCAT(SUBSTR(FIRST_NAME,1,1), ' '),LAST_NAME) AS NAME FROM OEHR_EMPLOYEES;
```

Comment: Great thanks for your help they both worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

`CONCAT` only allows you to concatenate 2 strings together, not more.
You should use:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTR(FIRST_NAME,1,1), ' '),LAST_NAME) AS NAME FROM OEHR_EMPLOYEES;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME|| ' '||LAST_NAME AS FULL_NAME
```

Comment: Please explain what your solution does.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(FIRST_NAME||' ',LAST_NAME) AS Name FROM EMPLOYEES;
```