# How to use if statements to conditionally execute SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a two fields `name_line1` and `name_line2` in database.

In the input form it is one field “name” but it is operated on by substr to get two `VARCHAR(30)` and assigned to the above two fields.

I would like to concatenate both fields together. But in the database, there is no trailing whitespaces for name_line1. I cannot use the following code from this link [Add SPACE to CONCAT with SUBSTR Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51926014/16034206) because there are cases where the point to substr is in the middle of a word (at n in Stationaries below):

```
                                 HERE
    Experimental unit 1998 Station|aries Sdn Bhd.
          name_line1                    name_line2
```

How do I write a code to conditionally concatenate white space if name_line1 is not 30 characters and name_line2 has characters or any other more relevant condition?

Comment: In Oracle, it's recommended you use `VARCHAR2` instead of `VARCHAR`.

Comment: You can use a case expression. Something like: `SELECT CASE WHEN LENGTH(name_line1) > 30 AND name_line2 IS NOT NULL THEN <concatenate white space> ELSE <don't concatenate white space> END as new_column` FROM your_table;` This is a bit of a guess though as your question isn't super clear. Please provide sample data and desired results from that sample data so we can understand better (assuming this case expression example doesn't do what you need).

Comment: @JNevill ok let me try that rn!

Comment: I am a bit confused. Do you want to split string from one field into two strings with length of 30 each or you want to concatenate two strings of the length of 30 into one. Please provide some sample data along with the expected result.  Like in the string "Experimental unit 1998 Stationaries Sdn Bhd." the letter n is at position 30 (in the middle of the word Stationaries )  it is one string what do you want to do with it? Or if it is composed of two strings that you want to concatenate then what are those two strings look like?

Comment: @dr that is the original string inputted in form. but in database, it was substr into two fields. I want to concatenate these two fields back together

Comment: Is _leading_ whitespace trimmed from `name_line2`?

Comment: @pilcrow For some reason, no. Only trailing whitespaces are trimmed from both

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Oracle doesn't remove white space when concatenating strings. Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=12f2079a06f0628c155a4480c77f18ac Can you show a code where Oracle trims your spaces?

Comment: it is not that the whitespace is removed when concatenating strings. When I want to concatenate the strings, the whitespace is not there. It is not in the database. It was there at point of insertion in the form, but not there in database. @ThorstenKettner

Comment: I found this link and it seems to best describe what is going on. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-32F22C8C-9208-458D-989B-C0E3A38BB258.htm#SUTIL1210 when data is inserted into table. The trailing whitespace is trimmed.

Comment: Yup, its pretty much solved. The case expression really helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so based on @JNevill's comment, I have used the following code:

```
Select vendor_id, 
    CASE 
         WHEN LENGTH(name_line1) <30 AND name_line2 IS NOT NULL THEN name_line1||' '||name_line2  
         ELSE name_line1||name_line2 
    END AS FullName 
from ap_vendors where vendor_id like '%YOULINE%';
```

The additional cases from @dr was helpful in considering if I missed out any potential loopholes, but after some consideration I decided that since any leading whitespaces in name_line2 would be intentional, its better to keep it as is.

The code should cover cases

1. where trailing whitespaces is removed from name_line1 by adding a whitespace,
2. covers substr in the middle of a word by concatenating without adding whitespace,
3. covers substr at end of word while name_line2 has leading whitespace, by concatenating as is without adding whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you need:

```sql
WITH sample AS
    (SELECT 1 "SAMPLE", 'Experimental unit 1998' "F1", 'Stationaries Sdn Bhd.' "F2" FROM Dual UNION ALL
     SELECT 2 "SAMPLE", 'Experimental unit 1998 Stationaries ' "F1", ' Sdn Bhd.' "F2" FROM Dual UNION ALL
     SELECT 3 "SAMPLE", 'Experimental unit 1998 Stationaries Sdn Bhd.' "F1", Null "F2" FROM Dual UNION ALL
     SELECT 4 "SAMPLE", Null "F1", Null "F2" FROM Dual UNION ALL
     SELECT 5 "SAMPLE", Null "F1", 'Experimental unit 1998 Stationaries Sdn Bhd.' "F2" FROM Dual)
SELECT 
  F1, F2,
    CASE 
      WHEN F1 Is Null And F2 Is Not Null THEN F2
      WHEN F1 Is Not Null And F2 Is Null THEN F1
      WHEN Length(RTRIM(F1)) <= 30 And Length(LTRIM(F2)) > 0 THEN F1 || ' ' || LTRIM(F2)
      WHEN Length(RTRIM(F1)) > 30 And Length(LTRIM(F2)) > 0 THEN F1 || ' ' || LTRIM(F2)
  ELSE F1
    END "THE_RESULT"
FROM 
    sample 
--
--  R e s u l t
--
--  F1                                           F2                                                 THE_RESULT                                                                              
--  -------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -----------------------------------------------
--  Experimental unit 1998                       Stationaries Sdn Bhd.                              Experimental unit 1998 Stationaries Sdn Bhd.   
--  Experimental unit 1998 Stationaries           Sdn Bhd.                                          Experimental unit 1998 Stationaries Sdn Bhd.  
--  Experimental unit 1998 Stationaries Sdn Bhd. NULL                                               Experimental unit 1998 Stationaries Sdn Bhd.   
--  NULL                                         NULL                                               NULL                                             
--  NULL                                         Experimental unit 1998 Stationaries Sdn Bhd.       Experimental unit 1998 Stationaries Sdn Bhd.
```

As you can see, using CASE with multiple conditions and intentionally removing spaces where they could be present (RTRIM / LTRIM) gives you opportunity to put a space where you want it to be. Also the result could be or should be a subject of TRIM.

Comment: this is useful because I probably missed a lot of other cases while writing the case expression. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your final two WHEN clauses read this way to me:  `WHEN a <= 30 and b THEN c; WHEN a > 30 and b THEN c`  That is, _any_ value of `a` produces the same output (and the other condition is the same between them).  How do you think those two clauses differ?

Comment: @pilcrow It is just a sample of how multiple conditions in CASE expression could be used. Acording to the question there even shouldn't be values longer than 30 characters. As a sample there are more not needed or unfinished stuff stuff in the sql like a lack of trimming of some of resulting values. It isn't a solution for exact data because there are not such data, I just wanted to show the posibilities hoping that the author of the question will do the job on his exact tables and columns. The data  I worked with are also just as a sample and they are senseless too. Regards...

Comment: P.S- and about your remark of last two WHENs - one could want to put different result in THEN clause if F1 is longer thae 30 chars. As mentioned above - this is just a sample of possible variations.....

Comment: Right - but the possibilities you show ... are the same. :)  "WHEN month <= September AND is_raining THEN wear_a_hat; WHEN month > September AND is_raining THEN wear_a_hat"  It doesn't matter what month of the year it is, I'm going to wear a hat in the rain.

Comment: You are right, obviously, there should be take umbrella in the other one, but the author of the question got it right and considered it usefull- it is up to him to do the job...